# django form exclude dynamic object from queryset

Tags: python, django, forms, init

I try to exclude a object from the form queryset by rewriting the init.
However i keep getting: TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
now i am pretty new to **init** function so im not sure where i go wrong.

My form:

```
class TravelForm(forms.Form):
    """ travel form, own location excluded """

    travel = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label=None, queryset=Region.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TravelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['travel'].queryset = Region.objects.exclude(**kwargs)
```

and in my view i use:
where request.user.character.region.name is the name of the excluded region (i dont know how to exclude something by object, hence the name)

```
def travel(request):
    travel_form = TravelForm(name=request.user.character.region.name)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not replace all named args in a `Form.__init__`. It is just simpler to declare a single new parameter:

```
class TravelForm(forms.Form):
    """ travel form, own location excluded """

    travel = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label=None, queryset=Region.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclude_args = kwargs.pop('exclude', {})
        super(TravelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['travel'].queryset = Region.objects.exclude(**exclude_args)
```

`kwargs.pop()` will remove `exclude` parameters from `kwargs`, if it is there. Otherwise, it will just return an empty dict `{}`.

Then you can instantiate your form with:

```
def travel(request):
    travel_form = TravelForm(exclude={'name': request.user.character.region.name})
```